# How do i pick specific cookies?

Tags: paw-app

How can I select specific cookies from a response?

The response I'm getting has 6 Set-Cookie rows, but I just need some of them for my next post.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 13:49:29 GMT
cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID-AUTH=0000Q77IB2vtdMjRmqnsja8ciUE:18j7lq1fl;Secure; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PD_STATEFUL_e0255922-d1d6-11e3-9144-005056bc2960=%2Fnauth2;Secure; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PD-SESSION-ID=1_4_0_Mip9xQRE1J80beniD1eh-7Le1L+X8uwfIRVUZdKvJUKO2OIB;Secure; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: iampsc1110=rd520o00000000000000000000ffff0a101fa3o1110;secure; path=/
Set-Cookie: TSaee27a=e4d514b3ab1503842b07e9b4d4ee0db30a6a3a54c730b09754f85edbe54ca44a641b9f7bf3fdf509ca7d6de2ed2d4e69c8c3db3f6623dd16fb85456b4ced6f5a34c171e7a460affd34c171e70025563134c171e75f534b1f34c171e7; Path=/
```

Comment: This is how the set-cookies is returned, though I just need some of them.
I have tried using the cookie response functionality but It gives me all of them, and I have responses before this where cookies will be collected to, and if I can't filter or select a specific cookie I will have duplicates.
Set-Cookie: PD_STATEFUL_e0255922-d1d6-11e3-9144-005056bc2960=%2Fnauth2;Secure; Path=/
Set-Cookie: PD-SESSION-ID=1_4_0_Mip9xQRE1J80beniD1eh-7O2OIB;Secure; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: iampsc1110=rd520o000001110;secure; path=/
Set-Cookie: TSaee27a=e4d514b3ab1503842b07e9b4d4ee0db30a6a3a54c730b09754f

Comment: There wasn't that much room in the comment field! :)

Comment: Edit your question and put it there?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is no proper way to do this yet. Here are 2 workarounds:

**Manually**, you can go and delete the cookies you don't want. In the *Requests* menu, pick *Cookies* then *Show Cookies*. Use the search box to find the cookies you'd like to get rid of.

**A more complex solution**, but that exactly fits your need, I think. Use a *Custom* dynamic value (right click on the field, and pick *Extensions* > *Custom*), instead, and use the following JavaScript code snippet:

```
function evaluate(context){
  // Set here the cookies you'd like to return
  var wantedCookies = ["datr", "reg_fb_ref"];

  var regex = /^(\w+)\=([^;\s]+)/g;

  // Request
  // Uses here the current request, you can use getRequestByName("name of the request") instead
  var request = context.getCurrentRequest();

  // Get response cookies
  var cookies = request.getLastExchange().getResponseHeaderByName("Set-Cookie").split(", ");
  var filteredCookies = [];

  for (var i in cookies) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var match = regex.exec(cookie);
    if (match && wantedCookies.indexOf(match[1]) >= 0) {
      filteredCookies.push(match[0]);
    }
  }

  return filteredCookies.join(",");
};
```

That basically parses manually the response cookies, and returns the ones you need.

[image: Filtering cookies in Paw]

Comment: Awsome answer! thanks, I will try it directly!
This brings me to the next question of thi, is there any way I would be able to export this entire flow I have built with requests.
So instead of exporting every request and rebuilding the dynamic parts I could get export this as a finished file?

Comment: I'm unable to add the PD-SESSION-ID cookie, it doesn't show up when I add it in wantedCookies

Comment: For some strange reason when I changed .split(", "); to .split(" "); I was able to get multiple values..

Comment: Yeah, it's all somehow hacky as it doesn't exactly parse cookies as it should. You probably can hack the code around to make it fit your needs.

Comment: About your first commend, you can save your Paw Collection like any file. Go to the File menu > Save. It should allow you to save it as a ".paw" file that you can easily share or backup.

Comment: I was thinking more of exporting it to php (curl) but that will just give me the separate requests, which means I will have to rebuild the dynamic parts there.

Comment: Yeah, there is no way to generate dynamic requests in PHP via Paw. It would add so much complexity :) Code Generators are more like a start-up help/template, not really aimed to be the final code you'll use.